# Does EFCore support multiple dbcontext for concurrent savings

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using a separate `DbContext` for each table in the database, they are each run independently in a `Task` to adding objects and `SaveChanges` are called in the task. Sometimes a `System.InvalidOperationException` was thrown:

```
2017-07-26 22:29:07.9670|ERROR|Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext|An exception occurred in the database while saving changes.
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__54.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.<SaveChangesAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.<SaveChangesAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
```

Does this mean that only one DbContext on a database is supported by EFCore?

Comment: I use two DBContexts, and it works. but I do save changes for each of them individually.

Comment: Seems like your threads are running OK, but it locks up whenever a `NonSucess` is thrown.`at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)`